# svn history via command line

Tags: svn, version-control, command-line

I am trying to write a utility in python to get me all the files that have been modified for a specific branch....i don't care about the date or who commited.

how would I go about doing this? I can handle the python part, I just can't find a command in svn to give me the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the "svnlook history" command:
[Subversion Complete Reference](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch09.html)

Comment: You should better give a complete example how to use the command here.

Comment: This will only run on the svn server where the repository is located and not on the client side. "Since svnlook works via direct repository access (and thus can be used only on the machine that holds the repository), it refers to the repository with a path, not a URL." From: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnlook.html .

Comment: "Repository argument required."

Answer (score 54):

```
svn log -l 10 path/to/file
```

Here 10 is number of entries from logs

e.g.

```
svn log -l 10 pom.xml
```

Comment: Any way to get a printout of the checkins for the entire svn repo folder? I'm thinking something akin to git log?

Comment: svn accepts as path:  1.directory with you own working copy, 2. http/https server side repository, 3. file:///base/path  local versioned svn database store.

Answer (score 14):

```
svn diff -r REV:HEAD --summarize
```

where REV is the revision in which the branch was created.

Comment: Using `svn log -v --stop-on-copy` shows the history until the branch creation: [How to find the common ancestor of two branches in SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015412/how-to-find-the-common-ancestor-of-two-branches-in-svn)